# Issue submitting form with Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to fetch the following page

http://www.stluciesheriff.com/inmate_list.php

using the fetch() method in UrlFetchApp class

To get the above page to display results, you've got to submit the form at

http://www.stluciesheriff.com/inmate_search.php

I've tried replicating the form data and headers using the fetch(url,payload) method, but for the life of me I can't figure out how to get it to return the actual data I'm wanting

Here's my attempt

```
function grabdata() {
  //var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Data");

  var postdata = {
    "First":"",
    "Last":"",
    "When":2,
    "Submit":"Search"
  };

  var payload = {
    "method":"POST",
    "payload":postdata
  };

  var data = UrlFetchApp.fetch("http://www.stluciesheriff.com/inmate_list.php",payload);
  Logger.clear();
  Logger.log(data.getContentText());
  return e; // intentional error thrown for debugger
}
```

I have a feeling I'm missing something obvious as I've never really had experience grabbing data from websites that require POST data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [Xml Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/service_xml) provided by Google. The Xml library can parse the html all the way down to the specific element that you need. I used the Chrome inspector to figure out which element I needed.

I wrote some sample script to get you going.

```
  var data = UrlFetchApp.fetch("http://www.stluciesheriff.com/inmate_list.php",payload);
  var entries = [];
  var xml = Xml.parse(data.getContentText(), true);
  var resultTable = xml.getElement().getElement("body").getElement("table").getElements("tr")[2]
        .getElements("td")[1].getElement("table").getElements("tr")[4].getElement("td").getElement("table");
  var tableRows = resultTable.getElements("tr");
  for (var i=1; i<tableRows.length; i++) {
    entries.push(extractDataFromRow(tableRows[i]));
  }

  Logger.log(Utilities.jsonStringify(entries));
  return entries;
}

function extractDataFromRow(row) {
  var obj = {};
  var tds = row.getElements("td");
  obj.name = tds[0].getElement("a").getText();
  obj.dob = tds[1].getText();
  obj.age = tds[2].getText();
  obj.inmate_id = tds[3].getText();
  obj.booking = tds[4].getText();
  return obj;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for that, but I think I was not clear in my OP - I'm unable to get any data when I post to the link. It doesn't contain any inmate data, just a blank page on the website

Comment: That's interesting, I think I might be misunderstanding how getContentText works. What was throwing me off is the fact that if I were to data.getContentText() immediately after pulling the data, I'd get the inmate website but with no data concerning inmates.. Just HTML - the "base" of the website if you will. I didn't make any attempts to parse anything as I assumed it wasn't there. You're right though, your snippet does work. Silly me!

Comment: Well, when you make a request to a website, of course you're going to get HTML code.